# Retrieve em-width from another font

Tags: fonts, spacing, dimensions, fancyvrb

I’m trying to align verbatim segments with their outputs. Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{IVerbatim}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=2em, gobble=2}

\begin{document}
Here is some verbatim text, indented by 2em:

\begin{IVerbatim}
  Do \textit{something}!
\end{IVerbatim}

Now here is its result, indented by 2em:

\begin{quote}
  Do \textit{something}!
\end{quote}

How can I get them to align?    
\end{document}
```

Both the `quote` & the `IVerbatim` environments are indented by 2em;
the trouble is that the em of the LMRoman font is wider than the em of the LMMono font.

(Correction: As mentioned in the accepted answer, the `quote` environment is actually indented by 2.5 em.)

How can I set the indent of my `IVerbatim` segments to be 2em of the roman font? This needs to be something I can plug into the line `xleftmargin=〈`*`something`*`〉`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the quad width (=`1em`) is controlled by `\fontdimen6`. According to `article.cls`, the indentation used inside a `quote` environment is `2.5em`, so you can say something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{IVerbatim}{Verbatim}{xleftmargin=2.5\mylen, gobble=2}

\newlength\mylen

\begin{document}
\setlength\mylen{\fontdimen6\font}
The value of \texttt{1em} is: \the\mylen

Here is some verbatim text, indented by 2.5em:
\begin{IVerbatim}
  Do \textit{something}!
\end{IVerbatim}

Now here is its result, indented by 2.5em:
\begin{quote}
Do \textit{something}!
\end{quote}

\tikz[remember picture,overlay] \draw[blue] ( $ (current page.north west) + (159.5pt,0) $ )-- ( $ (current page.south west)+ (159.5pt,0) $ );    

\end{document}
```

I only added the vertical rule for visualization purposes:

[image]

Another way to get the value for `1em` would be by measuring the length of a `\quad` space:

```
\settowidth\mylen{\quad}\the\mmylen
```

Here's a simple document showing the different values for the quad width depending ob the font family for the `lmodern` fonts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\newcommand\QuadWd{%
  The value of 1em is \the\fontdimen6\font\par}

\begin{document}

\QuadWd
{\ttfamily\QuadWd}
{\sffamily\QuadWd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there some way to do this as `xleftmargin=2.5\fontdimen6\rmfont` or something?

Comment: Suggested improvement: Together with the environment definition and the `newlength` declaration, put the line `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength\mylen{\fontdimen6\font}}`. Keeps logically-related things together. I’ve implemented this for my [`xpeek`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpeek) package [in this commit](https://github.com/jcsalomon/xpeek/commit/23be2f9).